# Product views counter on product page - opencart

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

My opencart version is **1.5.6**

I want to show product views counter on product page.

For example "Viewed by 350 people"

I installed vQmod and dragged-dropped a xml like in here:

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=103535

But it didn't work for **1.5.6**

This is I need:

[image]

Can you help please?

Comment: Are you using the opencart theme, or are you using a third party theme

Comment: @Brian I am using another theme. not opencart default theme.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are using a different theme, i would believe this is your trouble.

What you need to do is edit the XML of the product view counter, change:

```html
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl">
```

to

```html
catalog/view/theme/YOUR THEME NAME/template/product/product.tpl">
```

To find out the exact name of your theme, go to catalog/view/theme

In there will show you the exact file name of your theme, use that name in the xml and the view counter should work.

Comment: I already tried this. I changed the path correctly. But didnt work. Also it doesnt work for default theme :(

Comment: only way to see what is going on is to paste the xml of the product view counter and the product.tpl

Comment: I changed xml here: http://postimg.org/image/fg5lohl5h/
And i dont see like "Views: 465" in product page.

Comment: can you post one of the product tpl, so that i can see that you have the code the xml is searching for.